# Extract multiple tar.gz files

Tags: python, compression, conditional

I'm new here and in the world of Python scripting mostly with the arcpy module.
I hope you can help me with the trouble that I have.

I'm trying to develop a script to extract or uncompress multiple tar.gz files (I can do it properly) with the condition that if the file into the tar.gz file contains certain name only.

```
import os, tarfile, glob

ws = "workspace" out = "out workspace"

for tar_file in glob.glob(ws + "/*.gz"):

    tar = tarfile.open(tar_file,"r")

    for member in tar.getmembers():
        if "atribute 1" or "atribute 2" in member.name:    # here i'm failing
            tar.extract(member,out)
            print "%s extracted" %(member)
    tar.close()
```

I can´t create the condition if.
Any idea how can I uncompress only the files with the attributes that I want?
I'm trying to do this to extract only some bands of a huge LANDSAT 8 dataset.

Comment: Here is a [similar question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018512/reading-tar-file-contents-without-untarring-it-in-python-script) on stackoverflow.com that may assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it sounds like the attribute is part of the filename?

If so, then all you should do is:

```
if member.name.find("atribute 1") >=0 or member.name.find("atribute 2")>=:
```

This code will check if the attribute is any substring of the file name.